com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission permission not included - RE-OCCURANCE
On trying to upload my build to dev console I Was greeted with that error
A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.

This happened to me last year and I found the fix for this, to include
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/> and this worked perfectly well and was fine for the past couple of releases.  I have not changed anything in my manifest and I've uploaded and I am getting this error again.
Has anyone experienced this issue reoccuring.  I check the upload on dev console and I can see that there is instance of that permission
EDIT - ADDING MANIFEST FILE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=".permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> <!-- white list apps for deep linking -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
    
    <application
        android:name="singletons.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:allowBackup">
        <activity
            android:name=".features.order.automatedcheckout.view.AutomatedCheckoutQRCodeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AppStartActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".features.home.HomeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            tools:node="merge">
            
            <!-- Make sure you explicitly set android:autoVerify to "true". -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                
                <!--
                     If a user clicks on a shared link that uses the "http" scheme, your
                     app should be able to delegate that traffic to "https".
                -->
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            tools:node="merge" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.register.home.RegisterHomeActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".WelcomeActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".features.register.home.RegisterLoginActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".WelcomeActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".features.register.home.RegisterLDAPActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".WelcomeActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".features.register.details.RegisterDetailsActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.paymentmethods.PaymentMethodsActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.paymentmethodsadd.AddCreditCardActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.paymentmethodsadd.AddCreditCardWebActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.paymentmethodsadd.AddMealplanDirectAuthActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.ReferralActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.support.SupportHomeActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.support.SupportFAQActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.PromoActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.receipts.ReceiptsAllActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.receipts.ReceiptsIndividualActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.rateorder.RateOrderActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.profile.ProfileActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.order.menu.view.OrderMenuActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.order.details.OrderDetailsActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.order.checkout.CheckoutActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.order.checkout.pointsbreakdown.CheckoutPointsActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.order.checkout.CheckoutTenderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_managebarcode"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.order.pendingorders.PendingOrderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pending_orders"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.order.process.OrderProcessActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.rewards.ContestsStoreActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.rewards.RewardsStoreActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.rewards.RewardsPunchCardDetailsActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.rewards.RewardsHowActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.home.inboxfragment.HomeInboxMessageActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.more.pushmessages.PushMessageHistoryActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StartSelectSchoolActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.rewards.RewardsChallengesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rewards_challenges"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.rewards.RewardsLevelStatusActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.rewards.RewardsPointsHistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rewards_pointshistory"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.home.customwebview.CustomWebViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_custom_webview"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.order.scanqrcode.ScannedBarcodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_custom_webview"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="utilities.ImageCropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_custom_webview"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity
            android:name=".features.home.DeepLinkActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                
                <data
                    android:host="menu"
                    android:pathPrefix="/locationid"
                    android:scheme="mobileorder" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" 
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode" />
        <service
            android:name="singletons.MyInstanceIDService"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>

When I comment the line <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/> from the manifest and build the app.  I can see in the manifest_merge_blame_file that this permission is added by com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:21.4.0

As far as I know firebase analytics is forcefully inserting this permission into the manifest during the build process. Use this option Firebase documentation suggests to disable the AD_ID permission adding the following to the manifest <meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" /> or You can do conditional statements in Gradle like using productFlavors for handling the Flag.

@BobSmith thanks for that I should've mentioned that I already have that added

If that is the case can you post your AndroidManifest.xml ?

@BobSmith updated with manifest

As Google analytics uses that permission but in your case you told its getting added from measurement libs so try something like this
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:21.4.0") {         exclude(module = "play-services-ads-identifier")     }

Adding tools:node="remove" to the uses-permission element effectively removes the permission from the manifest when it's being merged, which is why the permission is not included in the final manifest. If you need the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission, you should not use tools:node="remove".
So it should look like this in your manifest.
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

